# Error loading Metaio ToolBox library

Tags: android, android-studio, metaio

I'm getting this error when loading the Metaio sdk in Android..
I do have all the native .so files loaded and in the apk as well as the metaiosdk jar included in the project.

The interesting part (i think) is at the bottom regarding the toolbox.. but I included the entire log to be safe..

The result is that the imager tries to start, then the app crashes and reboots itself. Any help would be appreciated..

```
07-16 23:23:32.757  30247-30628/com.test.metaioapp D/dalvikvm﹕ Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.test.metaioapp-13/libavutil.so 0x428a7278
07-16 23:23:32.757  30247-30628/com.test.metaioapp D/dalvikvm﹕ Shared lib '/data/app-lib/com.test.metaioapp-13/libavutil.so' already loaded in same CL 0x428a7278
07-16 23:23:32.757  30247-30628/com.test.metaioapp D/dalvikvm﹕ Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.test.metaioapp-13/libswscale.so 0x428a7278
07-16 23:23:32.757  30247-30628/com.test.metaioapp D/dalvikvm﹕ Shared lib '/data/app-lib/com.test.metaioapp-13/libswscale.so' already loaded in same CL 0x428a7278
07-16 23:23:32.767  30247-30628/com.test.metaioapp D/dalvikvm﹕ Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.test.metaioapp-13/libavcodec.so 0x428a7278
07-16 23:23:32.767  30247-30628/com.test.metaioapp D/dalvikvm﹕ Shared lib '/data/app-lib/com.test.metaioapp-13/libavcodec.so' already loaded in same CL 0x428a7278
07-16 23:23:32.767  30247-30628/com.test.metaioapp D/dalvikvm﹕ Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.test.metaioapp-13/libavformat.so 0x428a7278
07-16 23:23:32.767  30247-30628/com.test.metaioapp D/dalvikvm﹕ Shared lib '/data/app-lib/com.test.metaioapp-13/libavformat.so' already loaded in same CL 0x428a7278
07-16 23:23:32.767  30247-30628/com.test.metaioapp D/dalvikvm﹕ Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.test.metaioapp-13/libswresample.so 0x428a7278
07-16 23:23:32.767  30247-30628/com.test.metaioapp D/dalvikvm﹕ Shared lib '/data/app-lib/com.test.metaioapp-13/libswresample.so' already loaded in same CL 0x428a7278
07-16 23:23:32.767  30247-30628/com.test.metaioapp D/dalvikvm﹕ Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.test.metaioapp-13/libmetaiosdk.so 0x428a7278
07-16 23:23:32.767  30247-30628/com.test.metaioapp D/dalvikvm﹕ Shared lib '/data/app-lib/com.test.metaioapp-13/libmetaiosdk.so' already loaded in same CL 0x428a7278
07-16 23:23:32.807  30247-30628/com.test.metaioapp W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/metaio/sdk/jni/IToolboxCallback;)
07-16 23:23:32.807  30247-30628/com.test.metaioapp I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method com.metaio.sdk.jni.IToolboxCallback.add3DMapTrackingGeometry, referenced from method com.metaio.sdk.jni.MetaioSDKJNI.SwigDirector_IToolboxCallback_add3DMapTrackingGeometry
07-16 23:23:32.807  30247-30628/com.test.metaioapp W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 18294: Lcom/metaio/sdk/jni/IToolboxCallback;.add3DMapTrackingGeometry ()Lcom/metaio/sdk/jni/IGeometry;
07-16 23:23:32.807  30247-30628/com.test.metaioapp D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0000
07-16 23:23:32.807  30247-30628/com.test.metaioapp W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/metaio/sdk/jni/IToolboxCallback;)
07-16 23:23:32.807  30247-30628/com.test.metaioapp I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method com.metaio.sdk.jni.IToolboxCallback.onCameraCalibrationProgress, referenced from method com.metaio.sdk.jni.MetaioSDKJNI.SwigDirector_IToolboxCallback_onCameraCalibrationProgress
07-16 23:23:32.807  30247-30628/com.test.metaioapp W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 18295: Lcom/metaio/sdk/jni/IToolboxCallback;.onCameraCalibrationProgress (JF)V
07-16 23:23:32.817  30247-30628/com.test.metaioapp D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0000
07-16 23:23:32.817  30247-30628/com.test.metaioapp W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/metaio/sdk/jni/IToolboxCallback;)
07-16 23:23:32.817  30247-30628/com.test.metaioapp I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method com.metaio.sdk.jni.IToolboxCallback.onError, referenced from method com.metaio.sdk.jni.MetaioSDKJNI.SwigDirector_IToolboxCallback_onError
07-16 23:23:32.817  30247-30628/com.test.metaioapp W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 18296: Lcom/metaio/sdk/jni/IToolboxCallback;.onError (Lcom/metaio/sdk/jni/ETOOLBOX_ERROR;)V
07-16 23:23:32.817  30247-30628/com.test.metaioapp D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0004
07-16 23:23:32.817  30247-30628/com.test.metaioapp W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/metaio/sdk/jni/IToolboxCallback;)
07-16 23:23:32.817  30247-30628/com.test.metaioapp I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method com.metaio.sdk.jni.IToolboxCallback.onMapExtended, referenced from method com.metaio.sdk.jni.MetaioSDKJNI.SwigDirector_IToolboxCallback_onMapExtended
07-16 23:23:32.817  30247-30628/com.test.metaioapp W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 18297: Lcom/metaio/sdk/jni/IToolboxCallback;.onMapExtended (JJ)V
07-16 23:23:32.817  30247-30628/com.test.metaioapp D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0000
07-16 23:23:32.827  30247-30628/com.test.metaioapp W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/metaio/sdk/jni/IToolboxCallback;)
07-16 23:23:32.827  30247-30628/com.test.metaioapp I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method com.metaio.sdk.jni.IToolboxCallback.onNewMapFeature, referenced from method com.metaio.sdk.jni.MetaioSDKJNI.SwigDirector_IToolboxCallback_onNewMapFeature
07-16 23:23:32.827  30247-30628/com.test.metaioapp W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 18298: Lcom/metaio/sdk/jni/IToolboxCallback;.onNewMapFeature ()Lcom/metaio/sdk/jni/IGeometry;
07-16 23:23:32.827  30247-30628/com.test.metaioapp D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0000
07-16 23:23:32.827  30247-30628/com.test.metaioapp W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/metaio/sdk/jni/IToolboxCallback;)
07-16 23:23:32.827  30247-30628/com.test.metaioapp I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method com.metaio.sdk.jni.IToolboxCallback.onScaleOffsetCalibrated, referenced from method com.metaio.sdk.jni.MetaioSDKJNI.SwigDirector_IToolboxCallback_onScaleOffsetCalibrated
07-16 23:23:32.827  30247-30628/com.test.metaioapp W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 18299: Lcom/metaio/sdk/jni/IToolboxCallback;.onScaleOffsetCalibrated ()V
07-16 23:23:32.827  30247-30628/com.test.metaioapp D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0000
07-16 23:23:32.827  30247-30628/com.test.metaioapp W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/metaio/sdk/jni/IToolboxCallback;)
07-16 23:23:32.827  30247-30628/com.test.metaioapp I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method com.metaio.sdk.jni.IToolboxCallback.onStateChanged, referenced from method com.metaio.sdk.jni.MetaioSDKJNI.SwigDirector_IToolboxCallback_onStateChanged
07-16 23:23:32.827  30247-30628/com.test.metaioapp W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 18300: Lcom/metaio/sdk/jni/IToolboxCallback;.onStateChanged (Lcom/metaio/sdk/jni/ETOOLBOX_STATE;)V
07-16 23:23:32.837  30247-30628/com.test.metaioapp D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0004
07-16 23:23:32.937  30247-30247/com.test.metaioapp D/dalvikvm﹕ Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.test.metaioapp-13/libavutil.so 0x428a7278
07-16 23:23:32.937  30247-30247/com.test.metaioapp D/dalvikvm﹕ Shared lib '/data/app-lib/com.test.metaioapp-13/libavutil.so' already loaded in same CL 0x428a7278
07-16 23:23:32.937  30247-30247/com.test.metaioapp D/dalvikvm﹕ Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.test.metaioapp-13/libswscale.so 0x428a7278
07-16 23:23:32.937  30247-30247/com.test.metaioapp D/dalvikvm﹕ Shared lib '/data/app-lib/com.test.metaioapp-13/libswscale.so' already loaded in same CL 0x428a7278
07-16 23:23:32.937  30247-30247/com.test.metaioapp D/dalvikvm﹕ Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.test.metaioapp-13/libavcodec.so 0x428a7278
07-16 23:23:32.937  30247-30247/com.test.metaioapp D/dalvikvm﹕ Shared lib '/data/app-lib/com.test.metaioapp-13/libavcodec.so' already loaded in same CL 0x428a7278
07-16 23:23:32.937  30247-30247/com.test.metaioapp D/dalvikvm﹕ Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.test.metaioapp-13/libavformat.so 0x428a7278
07-16 23:23:32.937  30247-30247/com.test.metaioapp D/dalvikvm﹕ Shared lib '/data/app-lib/com.test.metaioapp-13/libavformat.so' already loaded in same CL 0x428a7278
07-16 23:23:32.937  30247-30247/com.test.metaioapp D/dalvikvm﹕ Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.test.metaioapp-13/libswresample.so 0x428a7278
07-16 23:23:32.937  30247-30247/com.test.metaioapp D/dalvikvm﹕ Shared lib '/data/app-lib/com.test.metaioapp-13/libswresample.so' already loaded in same CL 0x428a7278
07-16 23:23:32.937  30247-30247/com.test.metaioapp D/dalvikvm﹕ Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.test.metaioapp-13/libmetaiosdk.so 0x428a7278
07-16 23:23:32.937  30247-30247/com.test.metaioapp D/dalvikvm﹕ Shared lib '/data/app-lib/com.test.metaioapp-13/libmetaiosdk.so' already loaded in same CL 0x428a7278
07-16 23:23:32.937  30247-30247/com.test.metaioapp D/dalvikvm﹕ Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.test.metaioapp-13/libavutil.so 0x428a7278
07-16 23:23:32.937  30247-30247/com.test.metaioapp D/dalvikvm﹕ Shared lib '/data/app-lib/com.test.metaioapp-13/libavutil.so' already loaded in same CL 0x428a7278
07-16 23:23:32.937  30247-30247/com.test.metaioapp D/dalvikvm﹕ Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.test.metaioapp-13/libswscale.so 0x428a7278
07-16 23:23:32.937  30247-30247/com.test.metaioapp D/dalvikvm﹕ Shared lib '/data/app-lib/com.test.metaioapp-13/libswscale.so' already loaded in same CL 0x428a7278
07-16 23:23:32.937  30247-30247/com.test.metaioapp D/dalvikvm﹕ Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.test.metaioapp-13/libavcodec.so 0x428a7278
07-16 23:23:32.937  30247-30247/com.test.metaioapp D/dalvikvm﹕ Shared lib '/data/app-lib/com.test.metaioapp-13/libavcodec.so' already loaded in same CL 0x428a7278
07-16 23:23:32.937  30247-30247/com.test.metaioapp D/dalvikvm﹕ Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.test.metaioapp-13/libavformat.so 0x428a7278
07-16 23:23:32.937  30247-30247/com.test.metaioapp D/dalvikvm﹕ Shared lib '/data/app-lib/com.test.metaioapp-13/libavformat.so' already loaded in same CL 0x428a7278
07-16 23:23:32.937  30247-30247/com.test.metaioapp D/dalvikvm﹕ Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.test.metaioapp-13/libswresample.so 0x428a7278
07-16 23:23:32.937  30247-30247/com.test.metaioapp D/dalvikvm﹕ Shared lib '/data/app-lib/com.test.metaioapp-13/libswresample.so' already loaded in same CL 0x428a7278
07-16 23:23:32.937  30247-30247/com.test.metaioapp D/dalvikvm﹕ Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.test.metaioapp-13/libmetaiosdk.so 0x428a7278
07-16 23:23:32.937  30247-30247/com.test.metaioapp D/dalvikvm﹕ Shared lib '/data/app-lib/com.test.metaioapp-13/libmetaiosdk.so' already loaded in same CL 0x428a7278
07-16 23:23:32.947  30247-30247/com.test.metaioapp D/dalvikvm﹕ Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.test.metaioapp-13/libavutil.so 0x428a7278
07-16 23:23:32.947  30247-30247/com.test.metaioapp D/dalvikvm﹕ Shared lib '/data/app-lib/com.test.metaioapp-13/libavutil.so' already loaded in same CL 0x428a7278
07-16 23:23:32.947  30247-30247/com.test.metaioapp D/dalvikvm﹕ Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.test.metaioapp-13/libswscale.so 0x428a7278
07-16 23:23:32.947  30247-30247/com.test.metaioapp D/dalvikvm﹕ Shared lib '/data/app-lib/com.test.metaioapp-13/libswscale.so' already loaded in same CL 0x428a7278
07-16 23:23:32.947  30247-30247/com.test.metaioapp D/dalvikvm﹕ Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.test.metaioapp-13/libavcodec.so 0x428a7278
07-16 23:23:32.947  30247-30247/com.test.metaioapp D/dalvikvm﹕ Shared lib '/data/app-lib/com.test.metaioapp-13/libavcodec.so' already loaded in same CL 0x428a7278
07-16 23:23:32.947  30247-30247/com.test.metaioapp D/dalvikvm﹕ Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.test.metaioapp-13/libavformat.so 0x428a7278
07-16 23:23:32.947  30247-30247/com.test.metaioapp D/dalvikvm﹕ Shared lib '/data/app-lib/com.test.metaioapp-13/libavformat.so' already loaded in same CL 0x428a7278
07-16 23:23:32.947  30247-30247/com.test.metaioapp D/dalvikvm﹕ Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.test.metaioapp-13/libswresample.so 0x428a7278
07-16 23:23:32.947  30247-30247/com.test.metaioapp D/dalvikvm﹕ Shared lib '/data/app-lib/com.test.metaioapp-13/libswresample.so' already loaded in same CL 0x428a7278
07-16 23:23:32.947  30247-30247/com.test.metaioapp D/dalvikvm﹕ Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.test.metaioapp-13/libmetaiosdk.so 0x428a7278
07-16 23:23:32.947  30247-30247/com.test.metaioapp D/dalvikvm﹕ Shared lib '/data/app-lib/com.test.metaioapp-13/libmetaiosdk.so' already loaded in same CL 0x428a7278
07-16 23:23:32.967  30247-30631/com.test.metaioapp V/MediaPlayer﹕ decode(146, 0, 9520)
07-16 23:23:33.007  30247-30247/com.test.metaioapp I/SensorManagerA﹕ getReportingMode :: sensor.mType = 3
07-16 23:23:33.007  30247-30247/com.test.metaioapp D/SensorManager﹕ registerListener :: 7, MPL Orientation (android deprecated format), 20000, 0,
07-16 23:23:33.037  30247-30247/com.test.metaioapp V/MediaPlayer-JNI﹕ native_setup
07-16 23:23:33.037  30247-30247/com.test.metaioapp V/MediaPlayer﹕ constructor
07-16 23:23:33.037  30247-30247/com.test.metaioapp V/MediaPlayer﹕ setListener
07-16 23:23:33.037  30247-30247/com.test.metaioapp I/RES﹕ 2130837613
07-16 23:23:33.037  30247-30247/com.test.metaioapp V/MediaPlayer-JNI﹕ native_setup
07-16 23:23:33.037  30247-30247/com.test.metaioapp V/MediaPlayer﹕ constructor
07-16 23:23:33.047  30247-30247/com.test.metaioapp V/MediaPlayer﹕ setListener
07-16 23:23:33.047  30247-30247/com.test.metaioapp W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/metaio/sdk/jni/IToolbox;)
07-16 23:23:33.047  30247-30247/com.test.metaioapp E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'com.metaio.sdk.jni.IToolbox', referenced from method com.metaio.sdk.jni.MetaioSDK.CreateToolbox
07-16 23:23:33.047  30247-30247/com.test.metaioapp W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 1898 (Lcom/metaio/sdk/jni/IToolbox;) in Lcom/metaio/sdk/jni/MetaioSDK;
07-16 23:23:33.047  30247-30247/com.test.metaioapp D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0010
07-16 23:23:33.047  30247-30247/com.test.metaioapp D/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x4775 at 0x13 in Lcom/metaio/sdk/jni/MetaioSDK;.CreateToolbox
07-16 23:23:33.057  30247-30247/com.test.metaioapp D/ProgressBar﹕ setProgressDrawable drawableHeight = 0
07-16 23:23:33.097  30247-30247/com.test.metaioapp W/metaio-java﹕ Location provider already running!
07-16 23:23:33.107  30247-30247/com.test.metaioapp E/metaio﹕ 105: IMetaioSDK::startCamera: invalid parameters
07-16 23:23:33.107  30247-30247/com.test.metaioapp E/metaio﹕ onError: 261, IMetaioSDK::startCamera: invalid parameters
07-16 23:23:33.117  30247-30247/com.test.metaioapp D/MetaioCloudPluginTemplate﹕ JunaioARViewTestActivity.onCreate()
07-16 23:23:33.157  30247-30631/com.test.metaioapp V/MediaPlayer﹕ decode(147, 0, 5194)
07-16 23:23:33.227  30247-30631/com.test.metaioapp V/MediaPlayer﹕ decode(151, 44288, 11392)
07-16 23:23:33.257  30247-30247/com.test.metaioapp I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 21.042MB for 3686416-byte allocation
07-16 23:23:33.257  30247-30247/com.test.metaioapp W/AwContents﹕ nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
07-16 23:23:33.347  30247-30247/com.test.metaioapp D/ProgressBar﹕ updateDrawableBounds: left = 0
07-16 23:23:33.347  30247-30247/com.test.metaioapp D/ProgressBar﹕ updateDrawableBounds: top = 0
07-16 23:23:33.347  30247-30247/com.test.metaioapp D/ProgressBar﹕ updateDrawableBounds: right = 720
07-16 23:23:33.347  30247-30247/com.test.metaioapp D/ProgressBar﹕ updateDrawableBounds: bottom = 6
07-16 23:23:33.347  30247-30247/com.test.metaioapp D/ProgressBar﹕ updateDrawableBounds: mProgressDrawable.setBounds()
07-16 23:23:33.347  30247-30247/com.test.metaioapp W/AwContents﹕ nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
07-16 23:23:33.577  30247-30638/com.test.metaioapp E/metaio﹕ GLSL shader program failed to link: --From Vertex Shader:
    Error: varying variables do not fit in 8 vectors.
    --From Fragment Shader:
    Error: varying variables do not fit in 8 vectors.
07-16 23:23:33.587  30247-30638/com.test.metaioapp E/metaio﹕ GLSL shader program failed to link: --From Vertex Shader:
    Error: varying variables do not fit in 8 vectors.
    --From Fragment Shader:
    Error: varying variables do not fit in 8 vectors.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before i used updated version of metaio i also get same problem to resolve this issue please follow below steps.

**1)**[download](http://ar.metaio.com/download_sdk?_ga=1.95698463.2017217449.1397561320) Updated sdk from metaio and install .exe file and goto system folder like **C:\Users\xxx\Documents\metaio** and copy metaio sdk and paste it into your project.see the below image [image]

**2)**Add jar file in your libs folder of your project and add metaiosdk as a library project of main project and press ok.please see the below image[image]

**3)**I think nowthis will work enjoy;-)